# How to use rails_admin with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, admin, rails-admin

I have a Sinatra app and I want to use RailsAdmin as my admin engine with models in Sinatra app. How can I do that without having to duplicate the model code for RailsAdmin project

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be easily done. 
`rails_admin` relies on models being backed by `ActiveModel`, so you cannot feed it with your plain-ruby models.

You can try someting like this though https://github.com/ratnakarrao-nyros/sinatra-admin, but it doesn't look that well maintained.

Comment: Can I use Padrino's admin module in Sinatra? If there is anyway to seperate it out easily